# Android FAB button on touch ripple and lift on touch animation using StateListAnimator?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-animation, floating-action-button

I have a **FloatingActionButton** in my xml layout for **v21** and above as shown below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/share_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/ripples_on_touch"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_fab_resting"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/lift_on_touch"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

Now, I want to give it a ripple effect and lift on touch animation on touch. I have to make use of the stateListAnimator to apply the translationZ to it. Also, I have given a background ripple effect on touch. However, I am unable to get the effects.

This is my **drawable-v21/ripples_on_touch.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

This is my **animator-v21/lift_on_touch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="12dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="0dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

***PS: My FAB button has a resting elevation of 6dp and I would want a rise to 12dp when pressed as shown above. Any help would be appreciated.***

Comment: Is there no one available to answer this?